# Git pull all files but one

Tags: git, pull

So, let's say I have a github repo like this:

FILE 1 
FILE 2 
FILE 3 
FILE 4 
FILE 5 
**CONFIG.** file

Now, imagine that my config. file is specific for my machine, so when i'm going to push something to the repo, i just use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged FileName
git add -u
```

And I have no problem pulling either, but when my boss changes the repo's config. file, i need my pull to ignore it, or else, the project will no longer work on my machine (let's say his machine is Linux, and mine is Windows). The idea is:
 A git command just like the one above, but for pulling.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you add it to your `gitignore`? https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: (I don't mean to be picky, but `git pull` doesn't pull files)

Comment: Pull the updates